# Photo Competition 2022-01-17: Wood

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Wood

Living wood, dead wood, burning wood, wood with nails or screws. Pictures that elicit the smell of resin or sawdust.

This theme was suggested by [xenoid](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/75947/xenoid).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/photo-competition-2022-01-31-wood?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on January 31, 2022 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, film stock, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### out of the woods

[image: out of the woods]
Wicksteed park. Kettering. Uk

Pixel 3a

Answer (score 25):

## Raindrops on planks

[image: Raindrops on planks]

Canon 7D, EF70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM, ƒ/2.8, 1/2500s, ISO 640

[Original](https://www.flickr.com/photos/l0b0/41204532142/)

Comment: Did you add the raindrops in post? Or did you capture this whilst rain was falling onto the wood?

Comment: No, those are real drops. I don't do that kind of post-processing. Just stood on the deck and pointed the camera down.

Answer (score 23):

#### Morning Pines

Lincolnshire, UK
January 2022

[image]

Fujifilm X-T3, Samyang 12mm f/2
f/5.6, 1/100, ISO 1250

Answer (score 21):

**Regeneration**

[image]

Nikon D3100, Nikon Series E 50mm, f2, 1/60s, ISO 800.

Herning (Denmark), December 31, 2021.

Comment: Are those fireworks in the background?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes. The Danes start their fireworks early, the photo was taken around 10 pm. There was much more activity after midnight.

Answer (score 17):

**Logging Remains**
[image]
Quetico Provincial Park, Ontario, Canada; remaining of bits of a trestle used for logging probably around the 1920s.
Sony Rx100, 10.4mm (35mm equivalent: 28mm), f/8, 1/200sec, ISO 200.

Answer (score 15):

**Fungal infection**

OLYMPUS E-M10 Mark III
ƒ/4
1/100
60 mm
ISO800
Olympus 60mm macro lens

A severed limb, hosting fungus.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

**Three Trees**

[image]

Vienna, Austria / January 2010
Sony DSC-R1
f5.6, 1/80sec, ISO-160

Answer (score 11):

**Autumn**

[image]

A stack of cut wood with coloured leaves on top in the Botanical Gardens in Berlin-Steglitz, Germany. October 2019

Canon EOS 1000D, F/5.6, 1/60s, ISO 400, Sigma 18-200mm @144mm

Answer (score 10):

### Drift

[image: Drift]

A piece of drift wood sticking out of a lagoon at high tide, Cozumel, Mexico. Early 2019

Nikon D700; f9; 1/250s; ISO 400; Nikkor 80-400mm @ 400mm

Answer (score 9):

#### Driftwood

Lincolnshire, UK
April 2021

[image]

Fujifilm X-T3, XF 35mm f/2
f/5.6, 1/950, ISO 160

Answer (score 7):

**In safe hands**

OLYMPUS E-M10 Mark III
ƒ/4
1/60
25 mm
ISO250
Lumix 25mm prime lens

A bench in Moseley park, Birmingham carved from wood. There is a hand at either end.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Snow veil**

[image: Snow veil]

Ilmajoki, Finland, 2016, Canon EOS 70D, EF-S10-18mm, 1/160 s, f/5.6, ISO 100

Answer (score 6):

**Eucalyptus (Safeda Tree)** - The extremely big human shaped tree in a forest of Dugadda Town in Uttarakhand State. The tree surprised me when I see it for the first time and is quite a tourist attraction as well for many people.

[image]

ONEPLUS 5T PHONE

**Capture Date** - 12th June 2021

**Flash** - No Flash

**Focal length** - 4.10 mm

**Aperture** - f/1.7

**Exposure Time** - 1/50

**ISO** - 500

Answer (score 4):

### **Mushroom on a log**

[image: A mushroom on a log]

iPhone X, 28mm, f1.8, ISO 25, 1/40s

St. Marys, PA. January 3, 2022

Answer (score 4):

**Tree-way**

[image: Tree-way]

Derbyshire, UK, June 2021.

Walking through the woods I came across a huge area of felled trees, cut and laid out waiting to be taken away. Batches were marked with the name (I guess) of the buyer. The orange paint was barely visible in the colour original, but with all sorts of manipulation in PhotoScape-X I was able to bring out the text which also highlighted all the rings and saw marks in the wood.

Nikon D5300. 35mm, 1/500s, F11, ISO 320

Answer (score 3):

### **A tree on the quad**

[image: A tree with several branches]

iPhone X, f1.8, 28mm, 1/284s, ISO 20

UNC Chapel Hill. June 12, 2021

Answer (score 3):

## Apple Trees

[image]

iPhone 13 Pro, f1.8, 13mm, 1/150s, ISO 40

Marina Bay Sands Apple Store, Singapore. December 31, 2021.

Answer (score 2):

### Palatinate Forest

[image: Palatinate Forest]

Casio Exilim EX-ZR10

Kaiserslautern, Germany, April 2016

Answer (score 2):

**The God in the Wood**

[image: The God in the Wood]

A carving in the trunk of a tree in Panchgani, India on a rainy, monsoon morning.  August 25, 2013.

Canon EOS 400D, 35mm, f/4, 1/320 second, ISO 400

Answer (score 1):

## Tulip Poplar

Washington DC, 2019

Nikon D7000, 16mm, f/3.5, 1/2500, ISO 100

[image: tulip poplar]